# CHGJOB - so that all CL commands are logged to spool file?

Tags: ibm-midrange

I would like to run a CL program that does a bunch of CPYF and deletes. I would like to have a log file of all commands even those that are successful.

I thought that running CHGJOB in the CL before CL call would do this, but it does not work. No log is created.

```
CHGJOB   LOG(1 1 *MSG) LOGCLPGM(*YES)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CHGJOB LOG(4 0 *SECLVL) LOGCLPGM(*YES)`

Turns on maximum logging..

Is this a batch job or interactive?

If interactive, you probably need to `SIGNOFF LOG(*LIST)` for the system to keep the log after signoff.

Comment: that seems to work as hoped.
though SIGNOFF LOG(*LIST) is a bit brutal.